# In Firefox 8.0.1, chat doesn't always move text down to the next line

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, chat

Details:
Operating System: Windows XP
Browser: Firefox 8.0.1
Display resolution: 1600x1200
Window size: Maximized, with a 2-high Windows taskbar below it.

When in Gaming's The Bridge earlier today, I saw @agent86 post a message with a link at the end.  It looked like this:

[image: Chat with Link]

However, if I tried to click the link, this happens:

[image: Chat now obscures the link button]

I'm fairly sure the Flag, Star, and Reply buttons aren't supposed to obscure any text, but it made the link impossible to actually click.

Comment: This is a duplicate, but I can't find the original

Comment: @Fezziwig, maybe the original has been deleted, so this one is not a duplicate anymore? :)

Comment: Workaround: Use the arrow on the left to get the transcript permalink, then follow the link from there.

Answer (score 4):

That's totally by design and has always been like that. If just by moving your mouse cursor around the screen (and thus causing star etc. to appear in different places) you'd cause the text to jump around, we'd get a whole lot of complaints about seizures here.

Comment: It's possible to avoid obscuring things without having text jump around :P